# Correct Function Type for temporary value

Tags: rust, callback, closures

What is the correct function type for a "callback" function called inside a function?

```rust
fn or_else(value: u32, f: ???) -> u32 {
    if (value == 0) {
        f()
    } else {
        value
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```rust
or_else(0, || { 3 })
```

What is rust angry when I use `f: &dyn FnOnce() -> u32`?

Error:

```
cannot move a value of type dyn FnOnce() -> u32: the size of dyn FnOnce() -> u32 cannot be statically determinedrustcE0161
cannot move out of `*f` which is behind a shared reference
move occurs because `*f` has type `dyn FnOnce() -> u32`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

I have trouble understanding E0161.

Comment: It's because FnOnce needs ownership of the closure to call it, while Fn() only needs a reference and FnMut needs a mutable reference.

Comment: 1. If you know that the closure will be called only once, what type should you use? 2. Can you walk through why it doesn't have ownership in this case? How can FnOnce "have ownership" of the closure? Are FnOnce and the closure not the same thing?

Comment: Depending on how hot the fallback function is, and whether it actually needs the special powers of `FnOnce` over `FnMut`, I would say `&mut dyn FnMut()` or `impl FnOnce()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *most general* way to accept a function, in this case, is to make your function *generic*, using either of these syntaxes:

```rust
fn or_else(value: u32, f: impl FnOnce() -> u32) -> u32 {
```

```rust
fn or_else<F: FnOnce() -> u32>(value: u32, f: F) -> u32 {
```

This is saying: `f` can be of any type the caller cares to provide, as long as that type implements `FnOnce` (is a function that can be called once).

> What is rust angry when I use f: `&dyn FnOnce() -> u32`?

`FnOnce` is named after the idea that it can only be called once, but what it *actually means* is that the function value is *consumed* (moved) by calling it. Thus, once you call the function, you don't have it any more.

But if you have `&F` then you are not allowed to move the `F` value, because you don't own it. So, it is impossible to call a `FnOnce` by reference. (Similarly, a `FnMut` requires a *mutable* reference, and cannot be called with an immutable reference.)

So, the type `&dyn FnOnce` is useless — it can exist, but it can never be called. If you want to use `dyn` (which can be a reasonable choice) then you have to use `&dyn Fn` or `&mut dyn FnMut`.

But, for a general-purpose function taking a callback, it is usually best to use generics *instead of* `dyn`. This is because:

- it allows you to accept `FnOnce`, the most general function trait
- it allows the function to be passed by value *or* by reference, if that is possible for the specific function, because references to `Fn`/`FnMut` functions also implement `Fn`/`FnMut` themselves
- it allows the compiler to inline the callback function so the code can be optimized as a whole